# Just returning the text of elements in xpath (python / lxml)

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, lxml

I have an XML structure like this:

```
mytree = """
<path>
    <to>
        <nodes>
            <info>1</info>
            <info>2</info>
            <info>3</info>
        </nodes>
    </to>
</path>
"""
```

I'm currently using xpath in python lxml to grab the nodes:

```
>>> from lxml import etree   
>>> info = etree.XML(mytree)   
>>> print info.xpath("/path/to/nodes/info")
[<Element info at 0x15af620>, <Element info at 0x15af940>, <Element info at 0x15af850>]  
>>> for x in info.xpath("/path/to/nodes/info"):
            print x.text

1
2
3
```

This is great, but is there a cleaner way to grab *just* the internal texts as a list, rather than having to write the for-loop afterwards?
Something like:

```
print info.xpath("/path/to/nodes/info/text")
```

(but that doesn't work)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use:

```
print info.xpath("/path/to/nodes/info/text()")
```