# Get 2 separate xpath values from one span with a line break

Tags: html, xpath, scrapy

I've got my HTML which looks like this:

```
<span>
Word 1
Sentence 1
</span>
```

I can extract it with:

```
//span/text()
```

which gives me

```
Word 1
Sentence 1
```

Is it possible in XPATH, to get/extract Word 1 and Sentence 1 separately?
(XPath extractor in Python for Scrapy)

I've tried:

```
//span/text()[1]
//span/text()[2]

substring-before(//span/text(),'\n')
```

but both were wild guesses and not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the first item "Word 1" with

```
normalize-space(substring-before(substring-after(translate(span/text(),'&#xd;',''),'&#xa;'),'&#xa;'))
```

and get the second item "Sentence 1" with

```
normalize-space(substring-after(substring-after (translate(span/text(),'&#xd;',''),'&#xa;'),'&#xa;'))
```

You can remove the `normalize-space(...)` if you don't need it.
The context node should be the parent of `span`, otherwise you should prefix the expression with `//`. Your main problem has been that there was a line feed (`\n`) before the first item.

EDIT:
I added a solution for handling the `CR` char for Windows' `CRLF`. It simply removes the `CR` char and acts on the `LF` char.

Comment: I see, thanks.  
But that would differ for HTML files which have been created on Linux and Windows? `\r\n` and `\n`

Comment: Good question. I added a solution for handling the `CRLF` situation. Its simple approach is removing the `CR` character from the input.

Answer (score 0):

See [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570632/just-returning-the-text-of-elements-in-xpath-python-lxml) to understand how to properly access the inner content of the element.

Then, process the output string to fit your needs.

Comment: Doesn't seem to address my question. I've added more content for clarification.